# How to add a localization to a settings.bundle?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, settings.bundle

My app supports two languages. When I add a settings-bundle, it´s only in english. In Xcode 6.1 I found no way to add a localization to Settings.bundle. Did I miss something?

[image]

Comment: Make sure that all the `Root.strings` file has no syntax error, i.e. `"key"  = "translation";`. Notice the `;` at the end. Files with syntax errors got silently ignored.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nevertheless I found a working solution.
1) open Settings.bundle package
2) create new folder de.lproj (dont´t duplicate en.lproj - Finder don´t likes this)
3) copy Root.strings from en.lproj-folder to de.lproj-folder
4) now you can edit the new language in Xcode

Comment: This works for me in Xcode 7.3 as well. When creating the new folders in step 2, duplicating the existing one (and renaming to e.g. de.lproj-folder) worked fine for me (El Capitan 10.11.4).

Comment: but one problem en.lproj folder doesn't contain strings I have currently in .plist file, all English titles are placed in .plist file

Comment: in case of Xcode9.4 it also requires to reopen the project to reflect the changes made in bundle.

Comment: you'll need to duplicate the .proj folders via Finder:
tutorial: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/localizing-iphone-app-settings-strings/

Answer (score 0):

It seems not working in Simulator. I am using Xcode 8.2.1.

OK. I find out the issue. In my Xcode project, the file `Root.plist` in `Settings.bundle`, there is one item missing: `Strings Filename`. I added this entry and set its value to `Root`, which is for language localization. With this missing item added, my app settings are working as expected in Simulator!

See my blog on [this for more information](http://davidchuprogramming.blogspot.ca/2017/03/localization-experience-in-swift.html).